# GCP components to orchestrate crons running in GCE (Google Workflows?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-workflows

I need to run a pipeline of data transformation that is composed of several scripts in distinct projects = Python repos.
I am thinking of using Compute Engine to run these scripts in VMs when needed as I can manage resources required.
I need to be able to orchestrate these scripts in the sense that I want to run steps sequentially and sometimes asyncronously.

I see that GCP provides us with a Worflows components which seems to suit this case.
I am thinking of creating a specific project to orchestrate the executions of scripts.
However I cannot see how I can trigger the execution of my scripts which will not be in the same repo as the orchestrator project. From what I understand of GCE, VMs are only created when scripts are executed and provide no persistent HTTP endpoints to be called to trigger the execution from elsewhere.

To illustrate, let say I have two projects *step_1* and *step_2* which contain separate steps of my data transformation pipeline.
I would also have a project *orchestrator* with the only use of triggering *step_1* and *step_2* sequentially in VMs with GCE. This project would not have access to the code repos of these two former projects.

What would be the best practice in this case? Should I use other components than GCE and Worflows for this or there is a way to trigger scripts in GCE from an independent orchestration project?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to not use GCE (Google Compute Engines) but instead create Docker containers that contain your task steps.  These would then be registered with Cloud Run.  Cloud Run spins up docker containers on demand and charges you only for the time you spend processing a request.  When the request ends, you are no longer charged and hence you are optimally consuming resources.  Various events can cause a request in Cloud Run but the most common is a REST call.  With this in mind, now assume that your Python code is now packaged in a container which is triggered by a REST server (eg. Flask).  Effectively you have created "microservices".  These services can then be orchestrated by Cloud Workflows.  The invocation of these microservices is through REST endpoints which can be Internet addresses with authorization also present.  This would allow the microservices (tasks/steps) to be located in separate GCP projects and the orchestrator would see them as  distinct callable endpoints.

Other potentials solutions to look at would be GKE (Kubernetes) and Cloud Composer (Apache Airflow).

If you DO wish to stay with Compute Engines, you can still do that using shared VPC.  Shared VPC would allow distinct projects to have network connectivity between each other and you could use [Private Catalog](https://cloud.google.com/private-catalog) to have the GCE instances advertize to each other.  You could then have a GCE instance choreograph or, again, choreograph through Cloud Workflows.  We would have to check that Cloud Workflows supports parallel items ... I do not believe that as of the time of this post it does.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. 
It seems indeed Cloud Run is very close to what I need since it provides with a http endpoint for the trigger. However it seems that the RAM limit is 8Go which is not enough for some steps of the pipeline.
I might stick to deploying the steps in Flask API in GKE where specs can be higher!

Comment: You bring up a good point ... a close cousin to Cloud Run is kNative ... see https://cloud.google.com/knative   The way to interpret this is that Cloud Run has a manifestation in GKE/Anthos ... where, if I understand it, GKE will spin up Pods when requests arrives, process the requests and then spin them down.  This means that if you run GKE/Anthos, you don't need to dedicate Pods to your work and hence keep resources free ... but when needed, they spin up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common request, to organize automation into it's own project. You can setup service account that spans multiple projects.

See a tutorial here: https://gtseres.medium.com/using-service-accounts-across-projects-in-gcp-cf9473fef8f0

On top of that, you can also think to have Workflows in both orchestrator and sublevel project. This way the orchestrator Workflow can call another Workflow. So the job can be easily run, and encapsuled also under the project that has the code + workflow body, and only the triggering comes from other project.